# Is it possible to send alerts from calender list before the start time of an event?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert, sharepoint-calendar, out-of-the-box

we are having a calender list.

Suppose we create an event with start time as 11:00am, then, is it possible OOB to send an alert (email) to the users (list column) at 10:30am (ie: 30mins prior to start time)?

Please guide on possible solution, OOB will be preferred.

Comment: have you think about workflow (I have no idea if you can use it) or, for sure, sharepoint timer job?

Comment: Yes, workflow, event receiver, timer jobs are an option but I was looking for something OOB like Alerts.. Anyways, how would workflow solve my problem? I beleive workflow is trigged on item change/create, then, how would it send reminder 30mins prior?

Comment: yes I agree with you but may be the Nintex Workflow can do that (I don't know). Anyway SharePoint Timer Job is what u looking for sure

Comment: Suppose I use timer job, then, what is the logic I should code?

Comment: Depends on your system and what u want have. U can check every min all your event in all your calendar in all your site collection. So depends how much big is your farm. Or you could have like a backup of those information somewhere (like sql) and have a trigger or... bla bla bla

Comment: Running timer job every minute may not be feasible as this will cause the site to run very slow..